# Search Questions you have previously asked or favourited

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Sometimes I find myself in the situation where I know I have favourited or asked a certain question and I would like to find it again, either for reference or to share.

Can this be done?

Comment: Asked: In the search bar, type `user:me is:q [tags] (search terms)`. Favorited: In the search bar `infavorites:mine [tags] (search terms)`. For more information, see [the search help page.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these searches can be preformed from the main search.

#### Your favorites:

> `infavorites:me something to search for`

#### You questions:

> `is:question user:me something to search for`

Check out the "Advanced Search Tips" button on the search page for tips on constructing advanced search queries.